# Multiple static files directories, single PHP FPM server

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I have two directories which I need to serve static assets out of:

1. `/srv/web`: Static assets which include images, JavaScript, HTML, etc.
2. `/srv/php`: Dynamic PHP scripts alongside some static assets.

I'm using NGINX and have configured it like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    # root /;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files /srv/web/$uri /srv/php/$uri =404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /srv/php;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
#       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/php$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, PHP FPM package version is 5.5.9, NGINX package version is 1.4.6.

The simple goal here is to serve static files out of `/srv/web` first, failing that `/srv/php`, failing that, return 404. All files ending in `\.php$` will be requested from PHP FPM over the Unix socket, and this is working.

The problem I'm currently having is that the `index` directive on the `server` isn't working as planned. I have an `index.html` file in `/srv/web`, and when I do

```
curl -is http://localhost/
```

I get a 404.

Is this the most ideal way of setting up an NGINX site with multiple filesystem folders to serve from alongside PHP? Any ideas as to why my static index isn't working?

---

#### Update

As per AD7six's answer below, I've updated my configuration to look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _; # listen at all host names

    # serve static files first from /srv/web, then from /srv/php, and any dynamic PHP files from
    # FastCGI/FPM at the Unix socket.
    location / {
        root /srv/web;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }

    location @php {
        root /srv/php;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /srv/php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/php/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

My directory listing looks like this:

```
/srv/
|-- php
|   |-- demo.php
|   |-- index.php
|   `-- phpstatic.txt
`-- web
    |-- static.html
    `-- subdir
        `-- index.html

3 directories, 5 files
```

Getting static files and PHP files works as planned and getting `/subdir/` with its index works fine, but if I GET `/`, I get a 403 forbidden, and nginx complains of directory listing:

```
2015/08/24 21:50:59 [error] 9159#0: *7 directory index of "/srv/web/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

Not sure why this is failing, but it smells like progress at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Multiple roots won't work like that

With this config:

```
server {
    # root /;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files /srv/web/$uri /srv/php/$uri =404;
```

There is no request processing that would use the index directive, as written the request must match a file. Using the debug log confirms this:

```
2015/08/24 08:12:11 [debug] 17173#0: *26 try files phase: 13
2015/08/24 08:12:11 [debug] 17173#0: *26 http script copy: "/srv/web/"
2015/08/24 08:12:11 [debug] 17173#0: *26 http script var: "/"
2015/08/24 08:12:11 [debug] 17173#0: *26 trying to use file: "/srv/web//" "/srv/web//"
2015/08/24 08:12:11 [debug] 17173#0: *26 http script copy: "/srv/php/"
2015/08/24 08:12:11 [debug] 17173#0: *26 http script var: "/"
2015/08/24 08:12:11 [debug] 17173#0: *26 trying to use file: "/srv/php//" "/srv/php//"
2015/08/24 08:12:11 [debug] 17173#0: *26 trying to use file: "=404" "=404"
```

Using a `try_files` directive that does look for directories like this:

```
try_files /srv/web/$uri /srv/web/uri/ /srv/php/$uri /srv/php/$uri/ =404;
```

also doesn't work:

```
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 http script copy: "/srv/web/"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 http script var: "/srv/web//index.html"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 trying to use file: "/srv/web//srv/web//index.html" "/srv/web//srv/web//index.html"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 http script copy: "/srv/web/"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 http script var: "/srv/web//index.html"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 trying to use dir: "/srv/web//srv/web//index.html" "/srv/web//srv/web//index.html"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 http script copy: "/srv/php/"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 http script var: "/srv/web//index.html"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 trying to use file: "/srv/php//srv/web//index.html" "/srv/php//srv/web//index.html"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 http script copy: "/srv/php/"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 http script var: "/srv/web//index.html"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 trying to use dir: "/srv/php//srv/web//index.html" "/srv/php//srv/web//index.html"
2015/08/24 08:16:17 [debug] 17651#0: *33 trying to use file: "=404" "=404"
```

Note that the "root" is confused, `try_files` expects a url not a file path. I suggest not to continue trying to use a solution of this kind - especially *not* setting the root as `/` and *potentially* allowing access to any file on the server.

### Use two location blocks

Instead keep things simple. This config will serve all the static content:

```
    root /srv/web;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/;
```

This config serves all php content:

```
    root /srv/php;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/;
```

Just put them together:

```
location / {
    root /srv/web;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    error_page 403 = @php; # see note below
}

location @php {
    root /srv/php;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    # as before
}
```

One gotcha is that with this kind of setup a request which matches a folder under `/srv/web` which *doesn't* have an `index.html` file will throw a 403 error (as the request is for a directory, and there is no directory index file). To allow these requests to also be handled by php - it's necessary to redirect 403 errors to the php handler.

Comment: [Here's my config](http://pastebin.com/UmR3ZWTG) based on your answer. It's failing to load index files with a 403, as it's not allowed to do a directory listing. PHP files are being 404'd. Static files from both places work, but the `index` is seemingly not working. My directory structure looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/pAzseVG1). Running a `curl -is http://localhost/` fails with a 403.

Comment: Just saw your last paragraph and updated my configuration, I think everything works now.